# Getting index of structured elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
mylist = ['name','mem','g1','g2','g3','foo','bar','qux','zoo','name','mem','foo','bar','qux','zoo']
```

We can see the string above to be separated into two parts, delimited by `'name','mem'`

What I want to do is to get two list where each list contain index of `foo...zoo` in mylist.
result in this

```
firstpart_vals_id = [5,6,7,8]
secondpart_vals_id = [11,12,13,14]
```

How can I achieve that in Python?

Everything in `mylist` is fixed, except the number of `foo....zoo` may varied, but the length  and content of `foo....zoo` section is same (symmetrical) for two parts.

**Update:** My attempt for regex solution.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby 
>>> import re 
>>> mj = re.compile(r'^val(\d+)$') 
>>> mylist = ['name','mem','g1','g2','g3','val1','val2','val3','val4','name','mem','val1','val2','val3','val4']
>>> [[x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(mylist), key= lambda x: mj.search(x[1].mj)) if k]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mj'
```

Comment: You have a list of 15 strings.

Comment: What about g1, g2, g3, how would you differentiate between them and fo, bar etc?

Comment: `g1,g2,g3` is fixed always. It'll never by any other thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> mylist = ['name','mem','g1','g2','g3','val1','val2','val3','valN','name','mem','val1','val2','val3','valN']
>>> [[x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(
                    enumerate(mylist), key= lambda x:x[1].startswith('val')) if k]
[[5, 6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Note that here I've used a simple `str.startswith` condition, you can replace that with regex if required.

### Update:

Using regex:

```
import re
mylist = ['name','mem','g1','g2','g3','val1','val2','val3','val1','name','mem','val1','val2','val3','val4']
mj = re.compile(r'^val\d+$')
print [[x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(
                     enumerate(mylist), key=lambda x: bool(mj.search(x[1]))) if k]
```

#### Output:

```
[[5, 6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

Comment: No I can't use `startswith('val')`, in reality this can be any text....let me revise the OP.

Comment: If you don't like `startswith` value you can use any other expression that returns yes-no for your string; including a regex match.   It's not clear from your question what the criterion would be so we have to guess.

Comment: If I understand this, it is breaking up the "vals" into blocks that were contiguous in the original, and ignoring the delimiters "name" and "mem".  What does the OP want if the original list was `["val1", "val2", "neither-val-nor-delm", "val3", "val4"]`?

Comment: How do you do that construct with regex? I tried this `mj = re.compile(r'val(\d)')` then `[[x[0] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(mylist), key= lambda x:x[1].mj) if k]` but failed.

Comment: @pdubois Use `mj = re.compile(r'^val(\d+)$')`, and then inside the lambda:  `key= lambda x: mj.search(x[1].mj)`.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: See my update...with regex. but still failed. Please advice.

Comment: @pdubois I've update the solution with regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions to do the basic steps (mapping and filtering of sequences) needed.  There are probably a few ways to get the job done, the code below is one way (N.B. I have not tested it).

```
# first find every occurence of "name", we just ignore "map". 
name_indices = [i for (i, s) in enumerate(mylist) if s == 'name']
name_indices.sort()  # probably redunant, but we are going to rely on sorting later.

# do something similar, but now we don't care about ordering so use a set.
# you can use some other sequence type if you prefer.  Of course we can use
# any condition we choose. not just s.startswith()
val_indices = set(i for (i, s) in enumerate(mylist) if s.startswith('val'))


# we want to build a dictionary of Name index to all value indices following it.
nv_map = {}
for ni, ni_next in zip(name_indices[0:-1], indices[1:]):
    # ni should be a name index, an ni_next should the next higher one.
    # so insert all val_indices in that range into an element of nv_map
    nv_map[ni] = set(i for i in val_indices if i >= ni and i < ni_next)
```

Thus we expect a result in `nv_map` of

```
{
    0 : {5,6,7,8},
    9 : {11,12,13,14}
}
```